# How to assign a variable outside php function

Tags: php, function, variables

I would like to be able to assign the name of a variable outside the function so that the function can assign the chosen variable. It does not seem to work. Anyone have any ideas?

Below is my attempt, however the `$admin` variable is empty after running the function.

```
function assign_check($variable, $check) {
    if (empty($_POST[$check])) {
        $variable = "no";   
    } else {
        $variable = $_POST[$check];
    }       
}

assign_check('$admin', 'admin');
```

My question is not about the use of global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a reference in the function body.

```
function assign_check(&$variable, $check) {
     $variable = 'hello';
}
```

And call passing a variable (reference).

```
assign_check($admin, 'admin');
```

`$admin` value is now 'hello';

Fitting that to your code would result in

```
function assign_check(&$variable, $check) {
    $variable = empty($_POST[$check]) ? "no" : $_POST[$check];
}

assign_check($admin', 'admin');
```

But returning a proper value would be much cleaner code than using references. Using a ternary operator like presented above would it even simplify without need of a function at all.

Comment: Because it bears repeating "But returning a proper value would be much cleaner code than using references." Don't use references unless you have a compelling reason to, and nothing here represents a good reason. @roelofco

Answer (score 1):

A normal way to assign the result of a function to a variable name specified outside the function would be to have the function return the result and assign it directly to the variable when you call the function.

```
function assign_check($check) {
    if (empty($_POST[$check])) {
        return "no";   
    } else {
        return $_POST[$check];
    }       
}

$admin = assign_check('admin');
```

I would do it this way unless there was a compelling reason to do it otherwise.

For the specific type of thing it looks like this function is intended to do, I would suggest looking at [`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php).